# What miracles were performed during the beatification and canonization processes of Mother Teresa?

Tags: miracles, saint, canonization

Mother Teresa was recently recognized as a Saint. The process of canonization (becoming a saint) involves the performing of a miracle. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonization):

> If the Venerable was not a martyr—all non-martyrs are "confessors" as they "confessed" or bore witness to their faith by how they lived their lives—it must be proven that a miracle has taken place by his or her intercession: that is, that God has shown a sign that the person is enjoying the Beatific Vision by God performing a miracle in response to the Blessed's prayers.

The first such miracle results in the person's beatification, recognized with the title "Blessed". The second such miracle results in the person's canonization, recognized with the title "Saint".

What were the miracles that were performed during the beatification and canonization processes of Mother Teresa?

Comment: Did you try [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_Teresa#Canonisation)? What questions remain?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is general reference.

Comment: I assume the O.P. means “during the beatification and canonization _processes_,” not during the actual beatification and canonization _ceremonies_ (which is what the question, as originally worded, would have meant). Please revert if the latter is what you actually meant.

Comment: @AthanasiusOfAlex I'd presume that the process only started after the first claimed miracle, so the question should really ask what miracles were verified during the process.

Comment: @curiousdannii No, the process begins on the diocesan level once there is evidence of sanctity of life. (There is minimum five-year waiting period, unless the pope waives it, as was the case with St. Theresa of Calcutta.) In any case, the miracle has to take place _before_ the actual beatification or canonization (i.e., the ceremony) takes place, obviously.

Comment: @AthanasiusOfAlex So what, the CC keeps an open file on anyone who lived an especially holy life, in case a claim of a miracle done in their name is made in the future? Are such files ever closed?

Comment: @curiousdannii I should point out that “process” in the Church is a technical legal term, like “procès” (“trial”) in French. The recommendation to beatify or canonize someone is done on the basis of a legal procedure that is similar to a trial. So technically, there is a distinct process (“trial”) done on the diocesan level, and two others (one for beatification and one for canonization) at the Congregation for the Causes of Saints.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes, a file is kept generally in the diocese where the person died. The files are “closed” if evidence of problems arises (something that would make the person not such a good example for the faithful to follow).

Comment: @curiousdannii They don’t keep files on everyone; generally, someone has to ask for it to be opened. Or else it is someone with a lot of notoriety (St. Theresa of Calcutta, St. John Paul II, St. Pio of Pietrelcina, etc.).

Comment: @Flimzy Isn't "Did you try Wikipedia?" the same as "Did you try Google?". Meta Stack Exchange has clearly said that we should [embrace the non-Googlers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280/191265), and I think that advice should follow for non-Wikipedians too. It's possible that an answer here may even turn up sources that could then be incorporated into Wikipedia articles.

Comment: @Thunderforge: To me, "Did you try Wikipedia?" is the same as "Your question doesn't show any research effort."  Which is the primary reason questions are *supposed* to earn down-votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first miracle, required for beatification, occurred in 1998 when a cancerous tumour was removed from the abdomen of an Indian woman named Monica Bersa, after a beam of light had emanated from a picture of Mother Teresa contained in a locket. This was recognised by the Church as a miracle in 2002. However the woman's husband disputes whether her cure really was a miracle. He says, "It is much ado about nothing. My wife was cured by the doctors and not by any miracle." However, Mrs Bersa asserts that her cure was miraculous and has sought financial help from the Sisters of Charity, accused the nuns of [abandoning her to a life of penury](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/1562284/Mother-Teresa-miracle-patient-accuses-nuns.html).

The second miracle accepted by the Church, leading  to canonisation as a saint, was the healing in 2008 of a [Brazilian man](http://thewire.in/18318/in-search-of-mother-teresas-miracle-in-brazil/) with multiple brain tumours.

Comment: @Thunderforge In my answer, I linked to one of many online articles on the first one. Controversy exists because both Mrs Bersa's husband & her doctors dispute it. Another link to look at is [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/asia/india/1443320/Medicine-cured-miracle-woman-not-Mother-Teresa-say-doctors.html). The second is not quite so controversial; I will add a link that discusses it. Remember, the only issue is whether there were two miracles.